# Static polymorphism using std::variant

Tags: c++, variant, static-polymorphism

I'm trying to implement something like static polimorphism using std::variant. I want to declare methods using VARIANT_METHOD or VARIANT_METHOD_CONST, that should take return type, method name, arguments, and qualifiers.

```
#include <variant>

#define VARIANT_METHOD(retType, name, ...) \
    template <typename... Args> retType name (Args&&... args) __VA_ARGS__ {                   \
    return std::visit([...args = std::forward<Args>(args)] <typename T>(T& self) -> retType { \
        return self.name(args...);                                                                   \
    }, static_cast<variant&>(*this));                                                                \
}
#define VARIANT_METHOD_CONST(retType, name, ...) template <typename... Args> \
    retType name (Args&&... args) __VA_ARGS__ {                                                    \
    return std::visit([...args = std::forward<Args>(args)]<typename T>(const T& self) -> retType { \
        return self.name(args...);                                                                        \
    }, static_cast<const variant&>(*this));                                                               \
}
#define VARIANT_FIELD(name) \
    decltype(auto) name() noexcept {                                \
        return std::visit([](auto& self) -> decltype(auto) {        \
            return self.name;                                       \
        }, static_cast<variant&>(*this));                           \
    }                                                               \
    decltype(auto) name() const noexcept {                          \
        return std::visit([](const auto& self) -> decltype(auto) {  \
            return self.name;                                       \
        }, static_cast<const variant&>(*this));                     \
    }

struct A {
    int field;
    int field2;

    int func(int a) const noexcept {
        return a + field;
    }
    int func(int a, int b) const noexcept {
        return a * a;
    }
};

struct B {
    int field2;
    int func(int a) const noexcept {
        return a * a;
    }
    int func(int a, int b) const noexcept {
        return a * a;
    }
};

struct C : protected std::variant<A, B> {
    using variant::variant;

    VARIANT_FIELD(field2);
    VARIANT_METHOD_CONST(int, func, const noexcept); // (1)
};

int main() {
    std::vector<C> vec;
    vec.emplace_back(A{.field = 0, .field2 = 1});
    vec.emplace_back(B{.field2 = 3});

    for (auto& c : vec) {
        c.func(10);
    }
}
```

I can't declare two methods with same names, but with different arguments. I want to write something like this:

```
VARIANT_METHOD_CONST(int, func, (int a), const noexcept);
VARIANT_METHOD_CONST(int, func, (int a, int b), const noexcept);
```

Comment: You could start by explaining what yoy're trying to do and what errors you are getting.

Comment: I want to declare method for 'struct C' with IDE hint of argument names
    VARIANT_METHOD(int, func, (int a));

Comment: Uhm... excuse me?

Comment: or declare two methods with same name, but with different arguments
VARIANT_METHOD(int, func, (int a)); 
VARIANT_METHOD(int, func, (int a, int b));

Comment: No, I meant you can start by editing your question to describe what you're trying to achieve and what error you are getting.

Comment: `I want to write something like this:` ok, and what should it result in?

Comment: @KamilCuk ability to write c.func(1); or c.func(1, 2);

Comment: I meant literally, what it should result in textually? So just write `int func(int) {} int func(int, int){}`? `: protected std::variant` Is inheriting from any `std::` class allowed? Why not just use composition? Why all the macros?

Comment: @KamilCuk struct C is a variant of A and B. macro VARIANT_METHOD_CONST  declares method which calls a method with the same name of struct A or B using std::visit

Comment: @KamilCuk macro VARIANT_METHOD(retType, name, params, ...) should expand to 'retType name params __VA_ARGS__ { return visit([params...](auto& self) -> retType { return self.name(params...); }, *this); } '

Comment: Then it's just `#define VARIANT_METHOD(retType, name, params, ...) retType name params __VA_ARGS__ { return visit([params...](auto& self) -> retType { return self.name(params...); }, *this); }` why not use it? I do not undersatnd the `params..` part - you _know_ the parameters, it's two ints. Do you really want `params...` there, not `[a, b]`? Please be specific. Please post the expected output in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest way I know of is to abuse `operator->*` and make polymorphic method pointers.  You can get the same syntax (except `->*` instead of `.`), no macros.

```
template<class F>
struct poly_member {
  F f;
  friend decltype(auto) operator->*( auto&& t, poly_member const& self) {
    return self.f(decltype(t)(t));
  }
  template<class...Ts>
  friend decltype(auto) operator->*( std::variant<Ts...>& var, poly_member const& self ) {
    return std::visit( self.f, var );
  }
  template<class...Ts>
  friend decltype(auto) operator->*( std::variant<Ts...>&& var, poly_member const& self ) {
    return std::visit( self.f, var );
  }
  template<class...Ts>
  friend decltype(auto) operator->*( std::variant<Ts...> const& var, poly_member const& self ) {
    return std::visit( self.f, var );
  }
  template<class...Ts>
  friend decltype(auto) operator->*( std::variant<Ts...> const&& var, poly_member const& self ) {
    return std::visit( self.f, var );
  }
};
template<class F>
poly_member(F)->poly_member<F>;
template<class F>
struct poly_method {
  F f;
  auto operator()(auto&&...args)const {
    return poly_member{[&](auto&& t)->decltype(auto){
      return f( decltype(t)(t), decltype(args)(args)... );
    }};
  }
  friend auto operator->*( auto&& t, poly_method const& self) {
    return [&](auto&&...args)->decltype(auto){
      return t->*self.f(decltype(args)(args)...);
    };
  }
  friend auto operator->*( auto* t, poly_method const& self) {
    return (*t)->*self;
  }
};
template<class F>
poly_method(F)->poly_method<F>;
```

a bit of [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) alphabet soup.  Replace the `auto` args with `template<class T>` etc for a [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) version.

You end up making the poly members like this:

```
constexpr poly_member field { [](auto&& t)->decltype(auto){ return t.field; } };
constexpr poly_member field2 { [](auto&& t)->decltype(auto){ return t.field2; } };
constexpr poly_method func { [](auto&& t, auto&&...args)->decltype(auto){ return t.func(decltype(args)(args)...); } };
```

and your code looks like:

```
for (auto& c : vec) {
    c->*func(10);
}
```

now if you don't like writing those constexpr lambdas, you can just make them be written by a macro.

Those poly methods and members work on any instance of any class that supports the lambda stored in them.  The difference between members and methods is that methods require a trailing () and pass in those arguments, and members do not.

For example:

```
A a;
a->*func(3);
```

acts on an `a` just like it does on a `variant<A, other stuff>`.

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/exEqMxE1E).

If you are really, really tied to your syntax, I'd advise looking at how google mock does it.

I sometimes extend this and write

```
template<auto*...methods>
struct poly_any:private std::any {
  // code that makes the above alphabet soup look cute
};
```

and dynamically build vtables for the `std::any` I store to access each `method`, giving you:

```
using C = poly_any< &field, &field2, &func >;
C c = A{};
std::cout << c->*field;
std::cout << c->*func(2,3);
```

where we type erase anything that supports the methods.

But that is my private insanity.  (this extension requires you mark up the poly members/methods with partial signature information).